# String matching for names with jumbled up words in R

Tags: r, string-matching

I am trying to match names in R similar to `VISHWANATHAN KRISHNA GURUVAYUR` and `GURUVAYUR KRISHNA VISHWANATHAN`. After removing spaces `levenshtein` gives a `21%` match.
I want to know if there is some string matching algorithm that could tag these two names as similar...

```
library(RecordLinkage)
levenshteinSim("GURUVAYURKRISHNAVISHWANATHAN","VISHWANATHANKRISHNAGURUVAYUR")

#[1] 0.2142857
```

Comment: Order the three words the same before you concatenate them?

Comment: There are millions of records in the table and the order of words is not defined. It could instead be `GURUVAYUR VISHWANATHAN KRISHNA` or `KRISHNA GURUVAYUR VISHWANATHAN`..

Comment: Why do you want the levenshtein distance between "abcdef" and "efabcd" to be 1?

Comment: Is the text in the table formatted with spaces?

Comment: in some cases the string is separated by spaces in some cases it is not.. for instance, `GURUVAYURVISHWANATHAN KRISHNA` could also be there.

Comment: @cory - I want some string matching algorithm that can tell me that these two names are similar..

Answer (score 0):

Try the Jaro-Winkler algorithm, also from the RecordLinkage package. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146091/how-do-i-edit-spelling-of-multiple-items-in-a-variable-in-r/36149393#36149393) for example, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) for more.

In your case,

```
jarowinkler("GURUVAYURKRISHNAVISHWANATHAN","VISHWANATHANKRISHNAGURUVAYUR")
```

yields:

> 0.7063492

Results are always between 0 and 1, so this is an improvement.